# How to store a struct into a variable in Rust?

Tags: rust

Rust allows declaring a structure inside a function but it doesn't allow assigning a variable with it in a simple way.

```
fn f1() -> (something) {
    struct mystruct {
        x: i32,
    }

    let s = mystruct;

    s
}

fn f2(s: something) {
    let obj = s { x: 5 };
    println!(obj.x);
}

fn main() {
    let s = f1();
    f2(s);
}
```

Is it possible to store a struct into a variable in a different way? How do I write the struct type correctly? In my project, I want to declare a struct inside a function and create instances inside of another one.

Comment: It looks like you started in programming with Rust. Please read [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/) as it explains all the details on how to write Rust programs and the syntax. If you still have questions, please comt back and ask them.

Comment: @hellow Yes, I did start programming in Rust. But it does not mean that my question is incorrect. For example, in Python it is not a problem to store a class into a variable.

Comment: I edited my question. If a macros helps I would be happy to see an example.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but now I ask you something. How is somebody outside of function `f1` supposed to know how your struct `mystruct` looks like? How do they know what kind of members it has, what size they are? It is not possible, you cannot use `mystruct` outside of your `f1` function

Comment: @hellow "How is somebody outside of function f1 supposed to know how your struct mystruct looks like?" That is what my question is about. This is why I want to store a struct into a variable somehow.

Comment: @hellow I edited the code again. I forgot to create an instance.

Comment: As said: No it's not possible. You have to define it in a shared scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to store a struct into a variable in Rust?

Rust is a **statically** typed language, and as such it is **not possible** to store a *type* into a variable, then use this variable to construct an instance of the type.

This is the reason you are not able to express what the type of `s` is; there is simply no vocabulary in the language for this.

---

Depending on what you want to do, you may wish to look into:

- Generics: `fn f2<T: Default>()` would allow creating an instance of any type `T` implementing the `Default` trait.
- Run-time polymorphism: A factory function `FnOnce(i32) -> Box<Trait>` could produce an instance of any type implementing `Trait` from a `i32`.

Comment: Thank you for nice explanation.

Comment: @Fomalhaut: You're welcome. Coming from a highly dynamic language like Python you are bound to bump into limitations that we're taking for granted; I'm looking forward to your future [rust] questions :)